Error: User memory limit exceeded. (Error code: 3)
I am studying land degradation and working on implementing the performance sub-indicator for land productivity based on ecoregions, linked to the LULC cover in 2022. However, I keep encountering the "User memory limit exceeded" error (Error code: 3).
To address this, I've divided the study area into four parts (Tile Reduction), adjusted the maxPixels parameter to 1e10, and set the scale to 100 to improve computation. I've also avoided adding and printing images to manage memory usage as recommended.
Are there additional strategies to resolve this error?
Here is my code link:https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fadeadenle%2FAPI_TRIAL%3APerformanceCOL2100NGS1A%20(copy)
Your help would be highly appreciated, thanks :)
To address this, I've divided the study area into four parts (Tile Reduction), adjusted the maxPixels parameter to 1e10, and set the scale to 100 to improve computation. I've also avoided adding and printing images to manage memory usage as recommended.
